# Avoiding string + integer addition when using recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to build a function(which uses function recursion) that scans a number, n, to look for a digit d, & if found, I would like to replace d with a specified number r, as shown in the code below. This code works fine but the output is in a string format. I have tried numerous ways to change it to output an integer but to no avail. Thanks for the help!

```
def replace_digit(n, d, r):
    number = str(n)
    i = 0
    if len(number) == 1:
        if number == str(d):
            return str(r)
        else:
            return number
    else:
        if number[i] == str(d):
            return number[:i] + str(r) + replace_digit(int(number[i+1:]),d,r)
        else:
            return number[i] + replace_digit(int(number[i+1:]),d ,r)
```

Comment: Is it an exercise? in other words, do you specifically required to use recursion? this is a very trivial task.

Comment: Just wrap the return value in a call to `int()`

Comment: Yeah, I have to specifically write in recursion, hence the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace_digit(number, digit, replacement):

    if number == 0:
        return number  # base case

    quotient, remainder = divmod(number, 10)

    if remainder == digit:
        remainder = replacement

    return replace_digit(quotient, digit, replacement) * 10 + remainder


print(replace_digit(961748941982451653, 9, 2))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
261748241282451653
```

Comment: Awesome. I was also thinking about a solution based purely on integer calculations, but I had the feeling that OP is actually struggling with understanding type conversions.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple but you need some type conversions between `str` and `int`:

```
def replace_digit(n, d, r):
    number = str(n)
    rest = str(replace_digit(int(number[1:]), d, r)) if len(number) > 1 else ""
    digit = number[0]
    digit = str(r) if digit == str(d) else digit
    return int(digit + rest)
```

There's also another possiblity, using a wrapper. This limits number of type conversions.

```
def replace_digit(n, d, r):
    def replace(n, d, r):
        rest = replace(n[1:], d, r) if len(n) > 1 else ""
        return r + rest if n[0] == d else n[0] + rest

    return int(replace(str(n), str(d), str(r)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a working function why not just split the problem ?

```
def replace(n, d, r):
    def replace_digit(n, d, r): # doesn't change
        return ...
    return int(replace_digit(str(n), str(d), str(r))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Was getting close to a solution of some sort like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to wrap the return values with `int()` as has been already been stated in the comments and other answers.

But here's a version that doesn't use string manipulation at all. Just for fun.

```
def replace_digit(n, d, r):
    rest = n // 10  # all but the rightmost digit
    digit = n - rest * 10  # only the rightmost digit
    digit = r if digit == d else digit
    if rest == 0:
        return digit

    return replace_digit(rest, d, r) * 10 + digit
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the concatenation try this:

```
if number[i] == str(d):
    new_number = number[:i] + str(r) + replace_digit(int(number[i+1:]),d,r)
else:
    new_number = number[i] + replace_digit(int(number[i+1:]),d ,r)

return int(new_number)
```